# How to delete user profile node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

Beginner here. I have created a userschema in mongoDB and maderegister and log in api, Here I can't figure out how to delete a user profile itself. I ve been hovering over the resources for long time, tried something without understanding. Please help me with the code and the explanation too.
Here's my '/register' route

```
router.post('/register',(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.body)

  const name = req.body.name;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const user = {
    _id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name,
    email,
    username,
    password
  }
```

You get an idea of my scheme and collection from here.
Here is my delete.jade view

```
extends layout

block content
    .container
        ul.errors
            if errors
                each error, i in errors
                    li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
        form(method='post', action='/users/delete/{{user.username}}', )
            h1  Delete Account
            p   Are you sure you want to delete your account?
            br
            button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Yes Do It
```

I have tried to make my delete endpoint like this which is inappropriate I know, But I didnt get any solid idea about delete functionality.

```
router.delete('/delete/username', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('username').findOneAndDelete({username: req.body.username}, 
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    console.log('got deleted');
    res.redirect('/');
  })
})
```

Comment: Your route is wrong. You should have `router.delete('/delete/:username', ...` So you missed the `:` for the variable parameter. And it's `req.params.username` then.

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Are you sure the collection in your DB es called username and not users or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is you are not getting the username from the request

```
router.delete('/delete/:username', (req, res) => {
    const { username } = req.params;
    db.collection('username').findOneAndDelete({username: username}, 
    (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    console.log('got deleted');
    res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Also on your front end, your form `method` needs to be `delete` to send it across as a delete request, not a post.

Comment: thank you so much for help, but here I am supposed to get my user name on my url link right?I am getting this http://localhost:3000/users/update/%7B%7Buser.username%7D%7D? , if i try to get that by id it returns localhost:3000/users/update/%7B%7Buser.id%7D%7D? I guess I am not getting my user from the collection deleted because of this error @scratk

Comment: from some of the resources in web i found that %7B%7 this comes as {{ and %7D%7D comes as }} instead of getting my username from my collection its not taking the command from the form

Comment: @ZeedTanue Trying this `#{user.username}`